# Can I add extra JS files to an Azure cloud service web role to be deployed?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-cloud-services

In our project we're generating a file on the fly from Gulp. It's not included in our project since it's a derived file and it changes every build, and we don't want it in TFS, and `.tfignore` just doesn't work as expected.

We do, however, want to output this file such that it gets deployed when the cloud web role in our solution gets deployed or packaged. The file needs to end up being accessible on the web at e.g. `/scripts/foo/bar.js`. I've been able to add it to the web role by the Add context menu option, but wasn't able to get it into the `siteroot` folder, onl the `approot` folder.

I've tried a few things I found online including adding tasks and content includes to the pubxml file for Azure but nothing really worked...

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What you need to add this task as a pre build step in Gulp task runner so it is included as a contest file while building your web role in the cloud service.

Comment: Did you mean to include a link? I'm not sure what you're referring to. I thought about using Gulp to copy files somewhere so they are included, but I don't know to which location they should be copied.